# macOS doesn't open apps but doesn't hang either

Tags: macos, applications, performance

Edit: Here is an [EtreCheck report](https://pastebin.com/DnZMnxg4)

Since this week, my Mac has sometimes gone into a weird state where I can do all of the following things:

- Type into text fields
- Open new Chrome tabs
- Switch Windows
- Move my mouse
- Everything feels smooth, there's no stuttering
- Open Raycast
- Use the application switcher

But I'm not able to do stuff like:

- Open applications
- Launch command line programs
- Interact with certain menubar apps
- Load websites in Chrome (although I can open new tabs in Chrome)

When my Mac is in this state, it takes about 1-5 minutes until I can use it again normally. Unfortunately I'm not able to view Activity Monitor or htop during this time, because the apps don't open.

After 1-5 minutes, I'm able to use my Mac normally again.

Any idea what this could be?

Here is my system info:

[image: About this Mac]

Comment: Can you switch Spaces? If so, leave Activity Monitor open on an otherwise empty Space - switch to it as needed & screenshot Memory & GPU tabs. [Set View to All Applications & set to sort by Memory & CPU% as appropriate]

Comment: Restart in Safe Boot mode, and see if that improves things. That will rule in or out third-party software you've installed that is conflicting with the OS in some way. When the Mac is working, I would use EtreCheck to generate a report about the state of your Mac. https://etrecheck.com/en/index.html Post a link to the report here. And try using a better browser, see if that helps. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @benwiggy. I've created a report here: https://pastebin.com/DnZMnxg4

Does anything in there catch your eye that might be causing this?

Comment: The Major and Minor issues reported by EtreCheck are all worth looking into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since doing an NVRAM reset and installing the latest (13.3.1) macOS update, the issue has not occurred anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the report, you've got ***loads*** of third-party software that's running at login, with lots of Launch Daemons, Launch Agents, and "launcher" processes, e.g. "BillieLaunchHelper", "BalanceLockLoginHelper", "EasyResLaunchHelper", "LaunchAtLoginHelper", "TupleLauncher", etc, etc.

Easy Move+Resize.app: that's exactly the sort of app I would expect might cause problems with the interface, if it hasn't been updated for Ventura.

Anything that messes with input, 'enhances' the interface, modifies OS behaviour, etc, has the potential for causing problems if it's written badly or just out of date.

Also test uninstalling your drivers for Wacom and 360.

Running in Safe Boot mode is a quick way to bypass all of this software and test whether it's causing the problem, or whether it's something else -- in that case, it could be the disk, as bmike suggests.

SIP has a 'custom' status: probably best to reset that unless absolutely mission critical for some reason.

Don't use CleanMyMac. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to always shut down the Mac and see if any apps hang or don't quit. Take casual notes of which apps you run and consider removing all apps from running at start (especially things like OneDrive / DropBox / Zoom / Mail / browsers / etc...). Also, I would disconnect from all networks / remove all accessories.

Then start in safe mode.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262

Start one app and see if it works (hold shift when you start the app to reset any saved state as well).

At this point you might have some more details for a new question or an edit to remove all the guesses and add some specifics.

For sure - open activity monitor so you can see what apps are using energy and CPU during the periods when it's working well.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/activity-monitor/welcome/mac

Lastly - make sure you have a backup of EVERYTHING important. This stuttering could be storage failure imminent and you might not get any more warnings before you have to think about data recovery.